# C# ASP.NET MVC Create Button is not working on click

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My create button isn't working when clicked on. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

I tried a few forums but they haven't solved the issue.

Controller:

```
using Rentals.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Rentals.Controllers
{
    public class GenreController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db;

        public GenreController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET: Genre
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Genres.ToList());
        }

        //getaction
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //post action to insert data into database
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Genre genre)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Genres.Add(genre);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

View (create.cshtml):

```
@model Rentals.Models.Genre
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h3> Create new Genre</h3>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name,"", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" />
    @Html.Partial("_BackToListPartial")
</div>
```

When I click on the create button it should add to the database. For some reason when I click it, it's not doing anything.

Comment: keep your html form in from action. Please refer youtube for basic mvc crud operations and html binding with actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the form around your HTML.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h3> Create new Genre</h3>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name,"", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" />
    @Html.Partial("_BackToListPartial")
</div>
}
```

Comment: @RahulSharma if you don't define the action and controller, it just does a post request to the same action. Which is how it's set up in the controller. I agree that most of the time it is good to specify the action and controller though.

Comment: @KevinLamb Yes, I did not see that `View` name is same as `Controller` action method. This will work.